# Sort list of lists in lexicographic order in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

I want to get the minimal element of a list of list of tuples

```
a = [[(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)], [(2, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)], [(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]]
```

in lexicographic order, so that `[(1,1),(1,0),(2,0)]] < [(1,0),(2,0),(1,1)]` ,
since the 0-th entry of the tuple has the greater priority, that is `1,1,2 < 1,2,1`,
and the 1-st entry has less priority.

```
min(a)
```

returns `[(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)]`, which of course is not correct.

I only need the index of the minimal element, so an incorrect version would be

```
print(min(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i]))
```

(both minimal element and index only methods would be appreciated).

Of course one could write a custom loop with zip or something, but I would like a solution with little overhead.

Comment: So you want to compare the `zip`ped tuples in each list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a custom key, zipping the tuples ([`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)):

```
min(a, key=lambda x: list(zip(*x)))
```

Output: `[(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]`

##### how it works

The default comparison of lists of tuples works by comparing the first tuples, then the second, etc. (sort of depth first while you want breadth first).

Since you want priority on the first item of each tuple, you need to reorganize the tuples. Internally, with this `lambda x: list(zip(*x))` `key`, `min` sees the items this way:

```
[list(zip(*x)) for x in a]
# [[(1, 2, 1), (0, 0, 1)], [(2, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0)], [(1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0)]]
```

And their sorted order is:

```
[[(1, 1, 2), (1, 0, 0)], [(1, 2, 1), (0, 0, 1)], [(2, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0)]]
```

Comment: This is interesting. Could you add some commentary to explain how it works?

Comment: @ciaranhaines sure I added some details, let me know if you need more

Comment: Couldn't you use `next` instead of `list` here? Like so: `min(a, key=lambda x: next(zip(*x)))` Just a minor improvement over evaluating the entire zip object to a list

Comment: @Jab OP said "less priority", not "no priority".

Comment: @Jab actually if you try on `b = [[(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)], [(2, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)], [(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1)], [(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]]` this will give an incorrect sorting

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sort key that picks up only the first element of each tuple:

```
sorted(a,key=lambda L:[k for k,_ in L]) # effective ordering

[[(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)], [(2, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)]]

min(a,key=lambda L:[k for k,_ in L]) # lowest/first value in that order

[(1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
```